# Cannot automate bower with gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, bower

I want `gulp` to run my `bower` and install all the files in `bower.json`. But it is not doing that. I am not getting any error also so I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong or not. Here is the code that I have written.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var bower = require("bower");
var util = require("util");

// console.log(util.inspect(bower, false, null));

gulp.task("bower", function(callback){
    bower.commands.install().on("end", function(installed){
        callback();
    });
});
gulp.task("default", ["bower"]);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the value of the `installed` state passed into the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring the main `bower` package and using it programatically. With gulp, it would be easier to use the `gulp-bower` plugin instead - https://github.com/zont/gulp-bower#usage